# Wait for loaded userdata in LoginService

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to load my user data node in my LoginService and wait before other services are loaded, because a part of the path to all other services depends on the userdata. ( in my case i want to save a gameid in the userdata node -> for example my user has asigned gameid: 1
the path to other data would be /1/chat, ... )

Auth.guard.ts

```
//Angular
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
//Services
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private loginService: LoginService,
  ){}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.loginService.getAuthenticated().map(user => {
          this.loginService.setUser(user);
          if(user) {
            return true;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
          }
    })
  }

}
```

Login.service.ts

```
//Angular
import { Injectable, Inject }     from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
//Rxjs
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
//Firebase
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, FirebaseAuthState, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, AuthMethods, FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
//Models
import { LoginModel } from '../models/login';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    public user: any;
    public firebase: any;
    public gameid: String;

    constructor (
        private router: Router,
        public af: AngularFire,
        @Inject(FirebaseApp) firebase: any
    ){
        this.firebase = firebase;
    }

    setUser(user): void { 
        this.user = user;
        //update last activity
        if(this.user != undefined && this.user != null){
          this.af.database.object(`users/${this.user.uid}`).subscribe(user => { this.gameid = user.gameid }
        }
    }
```

Chat.service.ts <-- here it crashes because the observable in Login.service.ts is not finished

```
//Angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
//Firebase
import { FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
//Services
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { MembersService } from '../services/members.service';
//Models
import { ChatModel } from '../models/chat';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {

  constructor (
      private loginService: LoginService,
      private membersService: MembersService,
      private router: Router
  ){}

    getLast(): Observable<any> {
        return this.loginService.af.database.list(this.loginService.gameid+`/chat/`)
    }

}
```

anybody can give me an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way is to provide an `Observable` in `LoginService` where all other services can subscribe to and which `LoginService` uses to notify other interested services and components about status changes.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private loginData:Subject = new BehaviorSubject();
  public loginData$ = this.loginData.asObservable();

  setUser(user): void { 
    this.user = user;
    //update last activity
    if(this.user != undefined && this.user != null){
      this.af.database.object(`users/${this.user.uid}`).subscribe(user => { this.gameid = user.gameid;
 this.loginData.next(...); }
    }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class ChatService {

  constructor (
      private loginService: LoginService,
      private membersService: MembersService,
      private router: Router
  ){
    loginService.loginData.filter(ld => ld != null).subscribe(res => 
      this.loginData = res;
      this.init(); // do additional initalization
    });
  }
```

Comment: @guenter thanks for your answer, i tried this already in a similar way, but my problem was that the getLast method of the chat is processed before the observable in the constructor is finished. in console this looks like this:
Line1 getLast. ID. undefinded
Line2 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Line3 Constructor. ID. 1

Comment: Where do you call `getLast()`? What about calling `getLast()` where I wrote `this.init()`?

Comment: getLast() is called in my app.component.ts, but this is just one of my whole services that are used in my app.. i also have a dashboard.component.ts which is routed by app.component.ts, where i have a lot of other service calls that are called at the ngInit() of the component.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a generic answer is possible. I assume you need to use observable operators like `merge` for `forkJoin` to chain the async calls together. Actually this isn't my area of expertise because I'm not using TS (only Dart), but there are lots of questions with answers about how to wait for other observables to complete.

Comment: i think there are not much observables to merge or something.. the easiest way will probably be to subscribe to the loginService.loginData in my service methods that are triggered in my components that are using ngInit()